# ValidateAntiForgeryToken in asp.net mvc 5.0 - how to pass array of objects with JSON and ajax

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-5, antiforgerytoken

It seems that `ValidateAntiForgeryToken` attribute prevents the data from being parsed properly when passed to MVC Controller, the code below works when I remove the `ValidateAntiForgeryToken` attribute but does not work with it, all the parameters in the controller action are passed except array of translations.

Please advise on how to pass array of objects while utilizing `ValidateAntiForgeryToken` attribute, is it even possible?

This is my code

C#

```
 [HttpPost]
 [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
 public void AddComment( string code, string type, string ecomment, IEnumerable<CommentTranslation> translations) 
  {
            //do something later
   }
```

CommentTranslation is

```
public class CommentTranslation
    {
        public string LangId { get; set; }
        public string LangName { get; set; }
        public string Translation { get; set; }
    }
```

js

```
addComment: function (ecomment, type, translations) {


        var data = {           
                code: '',
                type: type,
                ecomment: ecomment,
                translations: translations
        };

        var url = 'CommentsAjax/AddComment';
        return comments.repository.postDataWithToken(data, url);
    },

  postDataWithToken: function (data, url) {
        
        return $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            traditional: true,
            contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8',
            data: comments.repository.addAntiForgeryToken(data),
            url: getServerPath() + url
        });
    }


addAntiForgeryToken: function (data) {
    var token = $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val();
    data.__RequestVerificationToken = token;
    return data;
},
```

Comment: Did you have the following in the *form* element?

    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

If not then you did not have a valid token to pass.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using `FormCollection` that you can just generically pass anything into the Controller.